# Optimize Postgres Full Text Search Across Related Tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

I'm looking for a review of my search function. Details below.

I have the following tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_a (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    text_a text UNIQUE
    -- other fields ...
);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    table_a_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES table_a(id), 
    text_b text,
    -- other fields ...
    unique (table_a_id, text_b)
);
```

I need to search in `table_a` text combined from `text_a`  and `text_b` and return a table containing `table_a` instances, but not repeating, e.g maybe the search returns 2 records from `table_b` that points to the same `text_a`, in this case, the response should contain this single instance from `table_a` only once, for each `table_a` instance.

Other specification is put more weight on the `text_a`.

I already have this working, but maybe it can be done better, here is the code:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX table_a_text_a_gin_idx ON table_a
USING GIN ((text_a) gin_trgm_ops);

CREATE INDEX table_b_text_a_gin_idx ON table_b
USING GIN ((text_b) gin_trgm_ops);

CREATE FUNCTION search_combined_text(search text)
RETURNS SETOF table_a AS $$
    WITH summary AS (
    SELECT
        a.*,
        GREATEST(
            SIMILARITY(concat_ws(' ', a.text_a, b.text_b), search),
            SIMILARITY(a.text_a, search) * 1.5
            ) as sml,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.id) AS rk
    FROM table_a AS a
    INNER JOIN table_b AS b ON a.id = b.table_a_id
    WHERE (
        SIMILARITY(concat_ws(' ', a.text_a, b.text_b), search) > 0.3 OR
        SIMILARITY(a.text_a, search) * 1.5 > 0.3
        )
    ORDER BY sml DESC
    )
    SELECT s.id, s.text_a -- other fields..., except s.sml and s.rk
    FROM summary s WHERE s.rk = 1;
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Comment: Why tag `hasura` here? And did I understood correctly: this code works as expected but you are not sure it's the best way to do? So you're asking for review - right?

Comment: @AlexYu yes you got it right. The tag is because I'm using it inside hasura :) Can you make a review?